# Retrieving count and summing from many different tables with shared ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve the number of related subprograms where there is a shared master `Prgm_ID` in all of the tables in a SQL Server database. There's the master table `T_Program` which stores the basic info about the parent program, but there are about 20 other tables which contain info about subprograms related to the given `Prgm_ID` (I.E. If the program's ID is 11353 in the `T_Program` table, that ID may appear many times in each of the other tables with subprograms).

What I want to do is for each `Prgm_ID` in the `T_Program` table, get the count of all the subprograms for it and sum them and then see if that number is over 500. I am really not sure of how to approach this. This query returns the desired results for just one of the tables:

```
select Prgm_ID, COUNT(prgm_type_a_ID) as TypeA_Count
from T_Prgm_Type_A
order by Prgm_ID
```

What I want to do is find all the `Prgm_ID`'s that have a summed total of subprograms over 500. This query is returning one of the tables I want to be included in the total sum, but I want each of the tables counts added up and then summed for each `Prgm_ID` in a single column.

Based off the above query, if a given `Prgm_ID` returned a count of 200 in that query and then for one of the other tables it had a count of 350 and all the other tables were 0 for that `Prgm_ID`, I want the final select query's result to look like this:

```
| Prgm_ID | Subprgm_Count |
|  11353  |      550      |
```

If the final sum of all the different counts from the subprogram tables is over 500 I want it to show me the `Prgm_ID` and give me the sum of all those different counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `UNION ALL` to chain together queries to each of your tables like this, and then do a `COUNT` against your records, making sure to `GROUP BY` your Prgm_ID.

```
SELECT Prgm_ID, COUNT(ID) AS Subprgm_Count FROM (
    SELECT a.prgm_type_a_ID AS ID, Prgm_ID FROM TableA a UNION ALL
    SELECT b.prgm_type_b_ID, b.Prgm_ID FROM TableB b UNION ALL
    SELECT c.prgm_type_c_ID, c.Prgm_ID FROM TableC c
)t
GROUP BY Prgm_ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) >= 5 --Your limit here
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1eb54/8)

Comment: This worked, although I did have to alter the query instead of `*` to use the same format as the first line of the subquery as there are other columns in these tables besides these two.